# Const variable declared in composition-api setup() not altered unless declared again within function scope

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

As a back-end developer, I'm quite new to the front-end, so I'm quite sure there's a concept or two I'm still missing. However, I haven't been able to find the solution to this problem.

I have a component in Vue(3) that receives a prop (an array) from its parent component. I pass this prop to a const variable so I can alter it, as props are not directly mutable. I'm working with the composition-API, so I've declared the const right at the start of the setup(props) function. Inside this setup function, I have a sort function in which I alter the contents of the prop. I splice the array (to empty it) and get the new contents from the back-end and push them into the array.

This doesn't seem to be working. It does however work when I declare the const within the sort function itself. Examples below:

```
setup(props) {
  const xs: x[] = props.x;

  //Called when @click
  async function toggleSortByProperty(property: string) {
    const ys = await axios.dosomething();

    xs.splice(0);
    xs.push(...ys)
  }
}
```

The above does not work. But if I declare the `const xs` right below the `toggleSortByProperty` line, then it magically works. However, this is not what I want, because I will be using that variable in multiple functions within the setup.

Some more peculiar info:

- When I hot-reload (which happens after saving a file) it suddenly works again;
- It seems the xs variable is undefined for only the first click and defined after that. This may be breaking stuff.

So, I'm kind of at a loss here. What gives?

Edit:
While I was editing this post, I was trying to fix this issue at the same time and I found the problem. It was a moment of stupidity from me. Turns out the problem was that the child component was created before 'x' was actually populated. I had recently swapped out my v-if for a b-overlay (BootstrapVue) in the parent component and it (obviously) only hid the child component instead of delaying its creation. This also explains why it works when the declaration of 'xs' is inside the toggle function.

Comment: How are you calling `toggleSortByProperty`? Are you *waiting* for it to finish? It's an async function, after all.

Comment: @VLAZ It's a button with an click event: click="toggleSortByProperty('title')". I don't believe this part is giving me any problems, but you raise a good point. The x prop is indeed passed down by the parent component, but the value within it is from an async get as well. It doesn't matter how long I wait until I fire the click event, the result is always the same. Yes, I believe this may be the problem, as the const is declared too soon while the props promise is still trying to resolve. What would be the correct way to wait for a promise to resolve, beside declaring the var in the function?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. That a parent causes it suggests that you didn't provide enough information.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yeah, my bad. I had actually ruled out any issues in the parent component, because everything seemed to be working fine in the child component until now. I forgot that I swapped out the v-if in the parent for a b-overlay (BootstrapVue), which caused the issue. I guess late night coding sessions really do bring out the worst in me..

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the xs variable inside a computed when making the return , so it will be something like

```
return {
xs:computed(()=>xs)
}
```

Otherwise based on the logic that you described  I would suggest that you don't make this request here , is the parent (who send the main result) responislbe for this type of operations sort, filter, etc.. and your component show data and it will be more clear and easy to unit test after this.